# How do i pass null to multipart @part in retrofit

Tags: android

I am making a post request in kotlin that takes optional files and a mandatory request body. When I pass null to the multipart file parts i get a 400 (Bad request response code), How do i include the part in my request but send no file

````
    @POST("transactions/recordTransaction")
    fun uploadTransaction(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Part brideIdFront: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part brideIdBack: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part groomIdFront: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part groomIdBack: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part chequePhoto: MultipartBody.Part?,
        @Part("transactionRecord") transactionRecord: RequestBody

    ): Deferred<TithePaymentResponse>```

My request in my viewModel


``` val uploadTithe =
                ApiService.DeliveranceApi.retrofitService.uploadTransaction(
                    token = "Bearer ${Constants.Token}",
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    transactionRecord = transactionRecordBody
)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to pass a null value to part

Declare multipart retrofit request as

```
 @Multipart
@POST("someEndpoint")
suspend fun someApi(
    @PartMap hashMap: HashMap<String, RequestBody?>,
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part?
): Response<ResponseClass>
```

in activity

```
var part: MultipartBody.Part? = null 
if (imageFile != null) { // check if image file is not null the pass file
        val imageRequestBody = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
        part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.path, imageRequestBody)
    }
```

if the image file is not null then pass the file as part otherwise pass part as a null